# Find Element Inside an Array, inside a Containing Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a Questions Array tht has two elements that are Player 1's questions and Player 2's questions. The questions are objects arranged like so:

```
var tempQuestion = {
    qId: i,
    leftQ: leftQ,
    rightQ: rightQ,
    correctAnswer: correctAnswer,
    allAnswers: sortedAnswers,
    questionText: questionText
}
```

I want to access the whole question object and pull this out into another array of current questions (one for each player), so both players have the same progress but they don't override each others questions. So I try to pull them out of the array with a find on the ID field (much like you would in a C# or VB MVC application).

```
for (j = 0; j < playerCount; j++) {
    // Pick a random question
    this.Questions.push(this.players[j].questions);
    var rand = this.Questions[j].length - 1;
    function findQ(q) { 
        return q.qId === rand;
    }
    this.CurrentQuestion[j] = this.Questions[j].find(findQ);
}
```

However this returns `CurrentQuestion` as a null value.

Debugging told me that this.Questions is populated, so there's no problem there and the player count is also populated so it's not that either. And the `this.CurrentQuestion[j] = this.Questions[j].find(findQ);` line is the one that breaks the application with the error:

> this.CurrentQuestion is null

Comment: for starters function declarations don't belong inside a `for` loop. Please provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what `this.CurrentQuestion` is

Comment: The message says the problem is with `this.CurrentQuestion.` How does that get initialized?

Comment: This is how this.CurrentQuestion gets initalised - so that is the best example I can give you - I've not missed anything

Comment: Then you need to first declare it as empty array. Javascript will not create one by default and that's why you get the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array `this.CurrentQuestion` must first exist before you can access it's elements

Before you start the loop add:

```
this.CurrentQuestion=[];
```